# Recovering Images from Formatted HFS+ Hard Drive

Tags: file-recovery, forensics

Is it possible to recover JPEG images using a low level scan of a hard drive?  The hard drive we originally formatted in HFS+ and has since been reformatted.  OS X has also been reinstalled.

Comment: You even reinstalled OS X? I'm fairly certain there's zero chance of recovering anything on that drive.

Comment: It's a friend's computer.  He ran Time Machine twice and thought he had backed up everything.  It turns out Time Machine doesn't back up iPhoto libraries when iPhoto is open (which is stupid).

Comment: Ouch.  That is good information to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the size of disks these days there's a decent chance that the OS X install missed overwriting the blocks containing the image.  You should try using one of the many "photo rescue" applications that search disks for JPEGs that were deleted in error.  Some of these apps allow free trial usage and make you pay only if the app recovers anything.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Nothing up to date.  It's been years since I used one of these programs, but when I did, it worked.  The program I used was called Photo Rescue Wizard.

Comment: Well, unbelievably Photo Rescue Wizard did the trick.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @helixed Sweet, glad to hear it.